# layout add block only template

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I think I have a little understanding problem how magento layout works.

I have a template `page/2columns-left.phtml` with the following code in it:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
```

Now in the page.xml I have:

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
        ...
        ...
<!-- Here comes my new block -->
        <block type="core/template" name="headmeta" template="page/html/head.phtml"/>
    </block>
</block>
```

As you can see I want to include the `page/html/head.phtml` in this block.
My first confusion was the block type. As I don't have any class to this template (I only have the phtml) I was not sure what to take as block type.
The `page/html/head.phtml` right now only contains 1 line of html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But right now the output of `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>` is empty.

What did I wrong? How can I include this block as a "sub-block" of `head` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `head.phtml`is allready in base and with that name I overwrited that template. All I needed to do was to take a name not taken yet for my head.phtml.